# React-Redux State won't update onClick

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

New to React. I am trying out react redux for the first time (on my own). I have a state for a gameboard called force_hidden that I want to set in App.js and then use in a child component ( a few levels down). I used redux to create forceGameBoardHidden that should set force_hidden to whatever value is inside the (). so, forceGameBoardHidden(true) should set the state of force_hidden to true. However, that doesn't happen. I can click on the item and it logs "before change" and then the state. In between it should have set the state to true, but the state is still false. I don't know what's going wrong here. I tried console.logging the gameBoardReducer. It fires when I start the page, but doesn't fire when I click the button.

gameboard.types.js

```
const GameBoardActionTypes = {
  FORCE_GAMEBOARD_HIDDEN: 'FORCE_GAMEBOARD_HIDDEN'
}
export default GameBoardActionTypes;
```

gameboard.action.js

```
import GameBoardActionTypes from './game-board.types';
export const forceGameBoardHidden = value => ({
  type: GameBoardActionTypes.FORCE_GAMEBOARD_HIDDEN,
  payload: value
});
```

gameboard.reducer.js

```
import GameBoardActionTypes from './game-board.types'
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  force_hidden: false
}
const gameBoardReducer = ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GameBoardActionTypes.FORCE_GAMEBOARD_HIDDEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        force_hidden: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default gameBoardReducer;
```

root-reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import gameBoardReducer from './game-board/game-board.reducer'
export default combineReducers ({
  gameboard: gameBoardReducer
})
```

store.js

```
const middlewares = [];
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
export default store;
```

index.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
```

App.js -- this is where the magic should happen in forceGameBoardHidden

```
const App = () => {
  const handleKeyChange = event => {
    setKey(event.target.value);
    console.log("before change")
    forceGameBoardHidden(true)
    console.log(store.getState().gameboard)
  }
  return (
      <SearchBox 
          onChange={handleKeyChange}
          placeholder="Enter your game Key"/>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  forceGameBoardHidden: item => dispatch(forceGameBoardHidden(item))
})

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: What do the [redux devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup) say? What actions are dispatched and what changes do they cause?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to dispatch the action, there are 2 methods , one is to connect the component to the actions and bind them to dispatch. The other one is much easier since you use functional components, is by using the useDispatch hook

Example here:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux' // <-- add this 

const App = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch() // <-- add this 

  const handleKeyChange = event => {
    setKey(event.target.value);
    console.log("before change")
    dispatch(forceGameBoardHidden(true)) // <-- change this
    console.log(store.getState().gameboard)
  }
  return (
      <SearchBox 
          onChange={handleKeyChange}
          placeholder="Enter your game Key"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I forgot to add the `mapDispatchToProps ` function. I have since added it in the app.js section. I did make these changes too, just to see what would happen and it did the same thing